# Print unicode characters encoded

Tags: java, unicode

Let's say we have string like `P\u0159\u00edprava`
How can we print it out with Java (println, printf, ...) so the unicode characters won't be decoded?

*Final*

I ended up using something like this

```
String data = "P\u0159\u00edprava";
data = data.replace("\\","\\\\");
// "\\" is a single backslash "\\\\" then double backslashes
System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the backslashes:

```
System.out.println("P\\u0159\\u00edprava");
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding '\' before your own '\' characters should do the trick:

```
System.out.println("P\\u0159\\u00edprava");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringEscapeUtils` of [commons-lang3](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

The code is here (see the method `public boolean translate(int codepoint, Writer out) throws IOException`): http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/translate/UnicodeEscaper.java?revision=1148520&view=markup

Comment: this is elegant, but as it needs additional library to be included, i'm not very interested in using this solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just have a look at the source and write your own small routine. It's just 10 lines.